# Filtering repos using GitHub search

Tags: filter, github-api

I am trying to filter out as many as repos possible for selecting candidate repos for an analysis. Since GitHub REST API has string rate limits, I tested my query in GitHub search (web). I get weird results. Here is an example.

Query 1: `language:Python archived:False is:public`
Output: 1.8M

Query 2: `language:Python archived:False is:public -topic:tutorial`
Output: 1.7M

Query 3: `language:Python archived:False is:public -topic:education`
Output: 1.6M

Query 4: `language:Python archived:False is:public -topic:education,tutorial`
Output: 1.7M

According to the [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/issues/planning-and-tracking-with-projects/customizing-views-in-your-project/filtering-projects#negating-a-filter), the negative qualifier in Query 4 should result less than 1.6M as it removes repos with either 'education' or 'tutorial' as a topic.

What am I doing wrong in here?